# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Cannot insert duplicate key in object . In C#.net....Visual Studio 2010...framework 3.5

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm Developing a small windows application in C#.net in Visual Studio 2010 with framework 3.5. I use LinqToSql for database manipulation.

table name: cprofile

Fields of the table are:

```
custid                int (primary key),
custname              varchar(50),
address               nvarchar(MAX),
mobileno              nchar(10)
```

So i have changed the `'Is identity'` property of the `'cust id'` to `'yes'`. It automatically changes other 2 sub properties.

```
Identity Increment =   1
Identity Seed  =      1,
```

After these changes have been made in the table, it throws error when I try to save a new record.

> "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'cprofile'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: You probably just need to update your entity model from the database, so that the framework knows that 'custid' is auto-generated and should not be part of an insert/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too familiar with L2S, but I'd say Daniel is correct: update your model (usually on a context menu somewhere) from the DB.  That should prevent it from attempting to insert a value into your auto-incrementing ID column.

I believe there may be a way to have it set IDENTIY_INSERT ON, but I highly recommend against it.

If your table should not be in charge of setting the CustomerId (say, the business has some method of making that determination (especially in a non-linear way), leave your Customer Id column as the PK, but remove the Identity specificaiton from the column.

Comment: if remove the Identity specificaiton from the column, It throws "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_cprofile'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.cprofile'."

Comment: Then you're attempting to insert the same PK value when it already exists in your table.  You should only _not_ have an auto-incremented Identity key if you know you will have a truly unique identity derived by some business rule to use as your PK.  Even then I recommend an Identity column, but that's just me.  Your best bet is, indeed, probably Daniel Pratt's suggestion (as noted at the top of my post...)

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to use the same insert statement you were using before, you can no longer do that.  I'm not sure how it's done in the C# side of it, but in SQL, you'd have to run statements to turn identity_insert on, then run your statement.  Because you changed the column to identity, the table makes sure the next entry is always 1 number higher than the previous.  Because of this, you can't simply insert values into it.  If you want the table to create the identity value for you, simply remove it.  If my explanation doesn't help, hopefully this will.

Table Definition (Table1)
Col1  Identity
Col2  varchar(50)
Col3  bool

Insert statement before identity
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (1, 'Test', TRUE)

Insert statement after identity
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Test', TRUE)

When identity is on, you cannot specify the value without turning on identity_edit.  I'll see if I can find how to do that in Linq.

EDIT:  I also like what Daniel said.  Didn't think about that.

Comment: Or, better, change your code so it doesn't insert the identity column.  One of the points of making the Id auto-incrementing is so you don't have to insert a value into that column...

Comment: DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            cprofile cs = new cprofile();
            cs.custname = textBox1.Text;
            cs.address = textBox3.Text;
            cs.mobileno = textBox4.Text;
            db.cprofiles.InsertOnSubmit(cs);
            db.SubmitChanges();

this the code i have used to insert a new record....